# Convert C++ pointer to Python numpy array

Tags: python, c++, pointers

I am working on a **C/C++ DLL** which used `OpenCV`, and in this one I perform some operations. In this example, I change the contrast of an image I read on **Python**, transfer to the DLL to perform the operation, and get back the result on Python to display it. I am doing this using pointers on the first pixel of each image, but in Python I don't find the way to recreate correctly the image using this pointer.

I already verified the Mat object in C++ is continuous, and I check the result saved from the DLL which is correct. The problem is in Python for me, but I don't see where I do something wrong.

**The C++ class and function :**

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <thread>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

class EpsImageProcessing
{
    // -------------- Methods --------------
public:
    EpsImageProcessing();
    ~EpsImageProcessing();

    unsigned short * imAdjustContrast(void * ptrImg, int width, int height, int contrastValue);

    // -------------- Atributes --------------
    Mat imgResult;
    unsigned short *imgAdress;
};


unsigned short * EpsImageProcessing::imAdjustContrast(void * ptrImg, int width, int height, int contrastValue)
{
    // Get image and reshape it as Mat object
    Mat imgTemp = Mat(height, width, CV_8UC1, (uchar*)ptrImg);

    // Convert to double to perform calculations
    imgTemp.convertTo(imgTemp, CV_32FC1);

    // Calculate the contrast coefficient
    float coeff = (259*((float)contrastValue+255)) / (255*(259 - (float)contrastValue));

    // Change contrast
    imgTemp = coeff * (imgTemp - 128) + 128;

    // Convert image to original type
    imgTemp.convertTo(imgTemp, CV_8UC1);

    // Return result
    imgResult= imgTemp.clone(); // imgTmp is an attribute of the class of my DLL
    imwrite("imgAfter.jpg", imgResult);

    bool test = imgResult.isContinuous(); // return true

    imgAdress = imgResult.ptr<ushort>();

    return imgAdress; //imgResult.ptr<ushort>(); // (unsigned short *)imgResult.data;
}
```

**Then the C wrapper** to do the link between C++ and others langages like Python :

```
__declspec(dllexport) unsigned short* __stdcall imAdjustContrast(void* handle, void* imgPtr, int width, int height, int contrastValue)
{
    if (handle)
    {
        EpsImageProcessing* data = (EpsImageProcessing*)handle;
        return data->imAdjustContrast(imgPtr, width, height, contrastValue);
    }
    return false;
}
```

**And the Python code :**

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy, os, cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dirpath = os.environ['PATH']
os.environ['PATH'] = dirpath + ";C:/x64/Debug/" # include of opencv_world.dll


mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("MyDll.dll")
class mydllClass(object):
    def __init__(self, width, height, nFrame, path, filename):
        mydll.AllocateHandleImg.argtypes = []
        mydll.AllocateHandleImg.restype = c_void_p

        mydll.imAdjustContrast.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p, c_int, c_int, c_int]
        mydll.imAdjustContrast.restype = POINTER(c_ushort)

        self.obj = mydll.AllocateHandleImg()

    def imAdjustContrast(self, ptrImg, width, height, contrast):
        return mydll.imAdjustContrast(self.obj, ptrImg, width, height, contrast)



img0 = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\mg\\Downloads\\imgInit.jpg", 0)
imgC = myclass.imAdjustContrast(img0.__array_interface__['data'][0], img0.shape[1], img0.shape[0], -127)
imgAfter = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\mg\\Downloads\\imgAfter.jpg", 0)

image = numpy.zeros((img0.shape[0],img0.shape[1]), dtype=numpy.dtype(numpy.uint8))
for i in range(img0.shape[0]):
    for j in range(img0.shape[1]):
        indice = i*img0.shape[1]+j
        image[i,j] = numpy.uint8(imgC[indice])
newImg = numpy.ctypeslib.as_array(cast(imgC, POINTER(c_uint8)), shape=(img0.shape))

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(221)
plt.imshow(imgAfter)
plt.gray()
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('image saved from C++ DLL')
plt.subplot(222)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.gray()
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('image recreated in Python (for loop)')
plt.subplot(223)
plt.imshow(newImg)
plt.gray()
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('image recreated in Python (cast)')
plt.show()
```

And the final result on Python is :
[image]

Comment: You are returning an invalid pointer in your C++ function. The object it points to ceases to exist at the `}`. `imgTmp = imgTemp.clone();` looks suspiciously non C++

Comment: `clone()` creates a full copy of the array and the underlying data, to avoid send a pointer on a temporary object. and `imgTmp` is a Mat object create as an attribute of the class so at the end of the C++ function it still exist for me.

Comment: `imgTmp` has automatic storage duration. It is destructed at the end of the function. Using the returned pointer *at all* means your program exhibits *undefined behaviour*, which can manifest as *appearing to do what you want*, but there is no guarantee that will stay the case

Comment: I add a new atribute being an `unsigned short * addressImg`. Then I modify its value in the function doing `addressImg = imgTmp.ptr<ushort>();` and return this pointer `return addressImg;`. But I have the same result.

Comment: `imgTemp` still refers to the *local* `Mat`. Use a **different name** for your member

Comment: I renamed `imgTmp` as `imgResult` to avoid confusion with `imgTemp`. So now we have `imgTemp` only on the function, and `imgResult` as member of the class. But still same result sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173872/discussion-between-mathieu-gauquelin-and-caleth).

Answer (score 0):

I found that the small difference between the two "good images" (image saved in C++ and recreate in Python with cast method) are from the compression of the image (.jpg) which is different between Python and C++. Dealing with a png and the image created in Python with the C++ pointer is okay with the cast method.

So the problem now is about the two for loops which don't create the image from the pointer in a good way. Any idea?